# C# Why i can not split the string?

Tags: c#, regex

```
 string myNumber = "3.44";

       Regex regex1 = new Regex(".");

       string[] substrings = regex1.Split(myNumber);

        foreach (var substring in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The string is : {0} and the length is {1}",substring, substring.Length);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

I tried to split the string by ".", but it the splits return 4 empty string. Why?

Comment: Obviously this question needs more answers. ;-)

Comment: I've just been Regexed to death...

Comment: Are you going to mark Jon Skeet's response the answer or are you waiting for more info?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`.` means "any character" in regular expressions. So don't split using a regex - split using [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string[] substrings = myNumber.Split('.');
```

If you *really* want to use a regex, you could use:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"\.");
```

The `@` makes it a verbatim string literal, to stop you from having to escape the backslash. The backslash within the string itself is an escape for the dot within the regex parser.

Comment: @retide: Well I've given two suggestions, one for if you have some reason you haven't told us for using regular expressions, and one for if you haven't... if you don't *need* to use regular expressions, why do so?

Comment: `string substrings` should read `string[] substrings`, but that's too small for an edit.

Comment: @retide: Yes, with Regex you would have to escape the `.` with `@"\."` or with `"\\."`.

Comment: As much as I love Jon Skeet, 24 upvotes about string's Split?

Answer (score 6):

the easiest solution would be: `string[] val = myNumber.Split('.');`

Answer (score 4):

`.` is a reserved character in regex. if you literally want to match a period, try:

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"\.");
```

However, you're better off simply using `myNumber.Split(".");`

Answer (score 4):

> The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character
>   is. The only exception are newline characters.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Therefore your implying in your code to split the string at each character.

Use this instead.

```
string substr = num.Split('.');
```

Answer (score 3):

Keep it simple, use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method;

```
string[] substrings = myNumber.Split('.');
```

It has [an other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx) which allows specifying split options:

```
public string[] Split(
    char[] separator,
    StringSplitOptions options
)
```

Comment: The overload of `Split` that you are using has the `params` keyword. Therfore you can drop the `new char[] { }` and just specify the charcter directly. `public string[] Split(params char[] separator)`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex you do that by using `Split` method of string object

```
string myNumber = "3.44";
String[] substrings = myNumber.Split(".");
foreach (var substring in substrings)
{
   Console.WriteLine("The string is : {0} and the length is {1}",substring, substring.Length);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

In Regex patterns, the period character matches any single character. If you want the Regex to match the actual period character, you must escape it in the pattern, like so:

```
@"\."
```

Now, this case is somewhat simple for Regex matching; you could instead use String.Split() which will split based on the occurrence of one or more static strings or characters:

```
string[] substrings = myNumber.Split('.');
```

Answer (score 2):

The period "." is being interpreted as any single character instead of a literal period.

Instead of using regular expressions you could just do:

```
string[] substrings = myNumber.Split(".");
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Regex regex1 = new Regex(@"\.");
```

**EDIT:** Er... I guess under a minute after Jon Skeet is not too bad, anyway...

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to place an escape character before the "." - like this "\\."

"." in a regex matches any character, so if you pass 4 characters to a regex with only ".", it will return four empty strings. Check out [this page](http://metahtml.sourceforge.net/documentation/regex/regex_3.mhtml) for common operators.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 Regex regex1 = new Regex("[.]");
```